Error: Make index on Oracle table unusable- ORA-14048: a partition maintenance operation may not be combined with other operations
I have several partitioned Oracle table , Oracle Database 19c, in my program. I have list of indexes on the table and want to make them unusable before inserting data and rebuild them after inserting data. For local index, I use this script to check if index is not there create them and make it unusable and if index is there, makes it unusable:
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
  DECLARE
  current_date DATE := TO_DATE('2022-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'); -- Example value for current_date
  current_partition VARCHAR2(50);
  t_name VARCHAR2(100) := UPPER('table_test');
  col_name VARCHAR2(100);
  ix_name VARCHAR2(150); -- Constructed index name
  list_index SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('id'); -- List of columns for indexes
  index_exists INTEGER;
  BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.enable();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Starting the process...');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('List count: ' || list_index.COUNT);
  -- Fetch the partition name for the specified current_date
  SELECT partition_name
  INTO current_partition
  FROM all_tab_partitions
  WHERE table_name = t_name
  AND TO_DATE(TRIM('''' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                     EXTRACTVALUE(
                        DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE(
                           'SELECT high_value FROM all_tab_partitions WHERE table_name=''' || t_name || ''' AND partition_name=''' || partition_name || ''''
                        ),
                        '//text()'
                     ),
                     '''.*?'''
                  )), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = TO_DATE('14010910', 'YYYYMMDD', 'nls_calendar=persian') + 1;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Current Partition: ' || current_partition);

  -- Iterate through the list of columns to construct and check index names
  FOR i IN 1 .. list_index.COUNT LOOP
    col_name := list_index(i);
    ix_name := t_name || '_' || col_name || '_indx';
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Processing index: ' || ix_name);

     BEGIN
        -- Step 1: Check if the index exists
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO index_exists
        FROM user_indexes
        WHERE index_name = UPPER(ix_name) AND table_name = t_name;

         IF index_exists = 0 THEN
            -- Create the index if it does not exist
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Creating index: ' || ix_name);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX ' || ix_name || ' ON ' || t_name || '(' || col_name || ') LOCAL';
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Index ' || ix_name || ' created.');
        END IF;

       EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error creating index ' || ix_name || ': ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

      -- Step 2: Mark the local index partition as unusable
      BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Marking index partition as UNUSABLE: ' || ix_name || ', Partition: ' || current_partition);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || ix_name || ' UNUSABLE LOCAL PARTITION ' || current_partition;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Index ' || ix_name || ' partition ' || current_partition || ' marked as UNUSABLE.');

       EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error marking index partition ' || ix_name || ': ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No partition found for the specified current_date.');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
 END;
 /

When I run the script I receive this error:
 Error marking index partition TABLE_TEST_id_indx: ORA-14048: a partition maintenance operation may not be combined with other operations

What might be wrong with the query?

Your syntax. Just at a glance, I see you have the word LOCAL in an ALTER INDEX statement... that isnt' going to work. The only time you define an index as local is at create time. You'll have to read the online documentation for DDL syntax and or google up examples to get your syntax correct.

Also, it's generally not a good idea to be doing index DDL like this programmatically, especially having to mess with all that partition logic. Way too much messiness for such a simple problem. The only time when bypassing index maintenance would be (historically) a good thing is when you're loading bulk data, and if you're doing that, you should be using direct path loads that postpone index maintenance anyway. That means there's little benefit to disabling and rebuilding manually. Just make sure those inserts are direct path and not conventional.

Would you please give me your explanation in details in new answer?

@M_Gh: it would be worth your trying to formulate a solution with the comments you have been given. Paul may well write an answer, but of course you can use these hints to set your research on a productive path.

There is something of an ethic here on Stack Overflow that answers may not be exactly everything that the question author needs to type verbatim in order to proceed. When a comment/answer is given, the completion of the task is still for the question author to carry out.
